# Can we set Photoshop toolbar to 3 or more columns?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, plugin

Is there any way we can set the Photoshop toolbar to more than 2 columns?

My desired outcome would be having it at 4 columns to be honest. Currently, by default - and as far as I know - we can only switch between 1 or 2 columns. I'm wondering if there is a plugin of any kind which gives us more customization options for panels or the toolbar.

I've browsed Google and Youtube for any plugins but their search algorithms mainly return me the same stuff.

Any light?

Answer (score 1):

No there is currently no way to do this in photoshop.

**Thomas Zagler** has made a tool called [configurator reloaded](https://pixelsucht.net/configurator-reloaded-photoshop-panel/en/start/) that sortof does this though

PS: Illustrator can sort of do this as it can have multiple toolbars

Comment: Never used it, but Thomas Zagler has made one where you can make a custom tools container: [configurator reloaded](https://pixelsucht.net/configurator-reloaded-photoshop-panel/en/start/)

Comment: @Joonas Kiitos, i have updated to match new info.